# How do I add one more status as "edited by editor"?

Tags: editor

How do I add one more status as "edited by editor"?

The reporter write an article.

Then editor edit the article and set the status as "edited by editor”

Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature has been proposed for development over 7 years ago with no results up to now.

But, you can scrutinize and/or try the [WP Statuses plugin](https://github.com/imath/wp-statuses) from one of the BuddyPress contributors.